# Top Layout Guide won't start at top of screen in Xcode 6 storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, statusbar

I have 2 view controllers setup identically in a Storyboard. On one, the top layout guide goes all the way to the top (under the status bar), on the other the top layout guide starts just below the status bar.

On both view controllers, I have Extend Edges Under Top Bars (checked) and Adjust Scroll View Insets ->unchecked (not that I'm using a scroll view here).

I can't figure out why these are different in the storyboard, and thus at run time one view controller looks like the way it was designed, the other does not because items with constraints to that top layout guide will be 20px wrong.

Help.

Comment: did you figure out what was causing this misalignment?

Comment: I'm sure I did, or found a workaround, but can't remember right now what that was.